# How to open any app from standalone iMessage app

Tags: ios10, openurl, imessage

If we have a host app, then we can open Safari with openURL method:

```
[self.extensionContext openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"] completionHandler:nil];
```

But what if we have **standalone iMessage app**? Is there any trick to open another app from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apple Developer forums, Apple only allows you to open URLs in your parent app (in this case, iMessage for standalone iMessage apps).

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/54410

I believe to ask for more functionality, file an Apple bug report (feature request).